# Quiero que los iconos del BottomNavigationView se cambien automaticamente con onBackPressed escuchando la pagina en que este el usuario

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo hacer que cuando el usuario le da a `onBackPressed` quiero que los iconos del `BottomNavigationView` se cambian automáticamente según la pagina en que esté el usuario.

El `BottomNavigationView` funciona bien, pero necesito que los iconos, por ejemplo si tenemos 3 fragmentos y llevamos un rato metidos en la aplicación, quiero que cuando el usuario le da al `Back Button`, que no solo le vuelva a la pagina anterior pero los **iconos** también tienen que seleccionarse y deseleccionarse dependiendo de la pagina en que se encuentre el usuario en ese momento cuando el usuario le da al Back Button `onBackPressed`.

Cuando voy para adelante todo funciona bien y los iconos se cambian. Lo único es que no se cambian cuando el usuario le da al botón back... Y tienen que cambiarse según la página en la que esté el usuario.

Me imagino que el código lo tengo que escribir en `onBackPressed`…

**MainActivity**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new HomeBNVFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_search:
                mSelectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                seenNotification();
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
                editor.apply();
                mSelectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        return true;
    };

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home_tab_layout);
        if (fragment instanceof HomeTabLayoutFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
        } else if (fragment instanceof SearchFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_search);
        } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
        } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
        } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**Podria hacerlo asi?**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

        super.onBackPressed();

        if (mSelectedFragment.equals(new HomeTabLayoutFragment())) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
        } else if (mSelectedFragment.equals(new SearchFragment())) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_search);
        } else if (mSelectedFragment.equals(new AttendingEventFragment())) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
        } else if (mSelectedFragment.equals(new NotificationsFragment())) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
        } else if (mSelectedFragment.equals(new ProfileFragment())) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

**Actualizado**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

        boolean disableBack = (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 1);
        if (disableBack) {
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home_tab_layout);
            if (fragment instanceof HomeTabLayoutFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
            } else if (fragment instanceof SearchFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_search);
            } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
            } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
            } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola! una consulta, entiendo que el bottomNavigation ya maneja esto, Lo que quieres realizar es lo siguiente: 1 -> 2 -> 3, luego estando en 3 presionas back button, vuelves a 2?? y el bottomNavigation debería pasar de3 a 2 y ahora seleccionado el item de 2?

Comment: @rguzman solo quiero que los iconos del BottomNavigationView Tambien se cambien solos cuando el usuario le da al boton back. Osea que todo funciona bien, el unico problema es que los iconos cuando le doy al boton back no se cambian… Quiero que se cambien "escuchando" segun la pagina en que se encuentre el usuario… Me explico?

Comment: @rguzman es decir si estoy en ProfileFragment y anteriormente estaba en el HomeFragment cuando le doy al back tiene me tiene que volver al HomeFragment, pero Tambien los iconos del BottomNavigationView tienen que cambiarse Tambien... La primeras parte funciona bien, pero los iconos tienen que cambiarse cuando el usuario le da al back del icono seleccionado siendo icono_perfil a icono_home…

Comment: Claro eso si entiendo, solo quiero confirmar el comportamiento actual que tienes en tu app. Si tienes un activity y ahi n bottom navigation con 3 fragment, sea cual sea el fragment en donde estes si presionas back no se minimiza la app?

Comment: @rguzman no tio, todo funciona bien. Osea todo perfecto MainActivity, luego 5 fragmentos, y necesito que cuando alguien le da al back button que se cambien Tambien los iconos segun la pagina en que este el usuario. A parte de eso todo funciona bien...

Comment: @rguzman bueno, sabrias como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un solucionado seria la siguiente:

Crea una variable llamada `backDisable` de tipo boleano. Esta variable nos ayudara a evaluar en que momento se tiene que minimizar la app cuando se hace back, es decir este caso ocurre cuando en la pila de fragments solo se tiene un fragment, en ese caso como ya no existe fragments anteriores se debe minimizar la app. ( Esto también lo podemos controlar con el fragment manager, pero recomendaría crear esta variable por si deseas agregar alguna lógica adicional)

Ahora, estabas en lo correcto cuando mencionas que necesitamos utilizar el método `onBackPressed` , recordemos aqui algo, el método `super.onBackPressed()` es el que se debe llamar solo si deseas ejecutar el back del sistema, de caso contrario no se debería llamar. Es aqui donde vamos a ingresar nuestra lógica. Lo que vamos a hacer es preguntar a tu fragmentManager si tienes más de un fragment, si así es el caso tenemos que evitar hacer back del sistema y actualizar tu bottom navigation, caso contrario hacemos el back.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    bool backDisable = (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().getSize() > 1 )
    if(backDisable){
        // logica para actualizar tu bottom navigation
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Ahora para actualizar tu bottom navigation, lo que puedes hacer es sesearlo manualmente. para eso utilizaremos un método que es `bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId()`, pero antes de eso, vamos a preguntar cual es el current fragment para saber que item seleccionar. Para esto utilizaremos `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()`. Entonces juntado todo quedaría:

```
 // logica para actualizar tu bottom navigation    
Fragment x = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(ID_FRAGMENT)
    if(x instanceof Fragment1){
        bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(ID_DEL_MENU_DEL_ITEM_DE_FRAGMENT_1)  
    }else if(x instanceof Fragment2){
        bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(ID_DEL_MENU_DEL_ITEM_DE_FRAGMENT_2)
    }else{
        bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(ID_DEL_MENU_DEL_ITEM_DE_FRAGMENT_DEFAULT)
    }
```

Finalmente, solo tienes que reemplazar esas variables por tus ids y con eso ya tendrías una solución al problema.

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358082/bottomnavigationview-back-button-not-working-properly Estoy mirando esto ahora. No seria mas facil?

Comment: Hay muchas soluciones. De por si este es una de ellas. Pero lo principal es que entiendas como funciona el componente bottomNavigation de Android. Por eso trate de explicar más que todo los conceptos y no la solución en si. Pero si debería funcionar también esa solución :)

Comment: Ok, voy a intentarlo y te digo. La otra solucion lo he intentado pero no me va. Ahora te digo si me funciona...

Comment: Tio, en esta linea ```Fragment x = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(ID_FRAGMENT)``` el ID_FRAGMENT cual es?

Comment: Oye, cuando pones ```is``` eso es kotlin, no?

Comment: No me esta saliendo tio. Podemos habalar en el chat un momento por favor?

Comment: Sorry, ya lo actualicé, utiliza "instanceof" de Java.

Comment: He subido el codigo tal y como lo tengo ahora… No me funciona aun. La primera parte con el Boolean no me sale... no se como hacerlo… esta linea ```bool backDisable = (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment().getSize() > 1 )``` me sale en rojo el getFragment() todo el rato...

Comment: Es en plural. getFragments()

Comment: Acabo de subir una cosa… Puedes decirme si podria hacerlo asi? No se...

Comment: getSize es size sin el get verdad? Porque el getSize no me sale tampoco...

Comment: Si creería que si. Solo ten cuidado en llamar a onBackPressed antes de tus validaciones.

Comment: Si es el size del arreglo de fragments

Comment: Los iconos no se cambian con el onBackPressed… No se Subo el codigo como lo tengo ahora

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109895/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-rguzman).

Comment: Qué tal tío. Tengo una pregunta... Te puedo preguntar una cosa sobre este código ya que me ayudaste con ello en su momento?